# Pick recent modified date in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my table:

```
ID   AppName  DepCode   DepName     Group     ModifiedDate   YearlyAmount
1    Nestle    NS      Foods        Products     01/12/14          451 
1    Nestle    NS      Foods        Products     01/17/14          495                
2    Oracle    OR      Software       Info       01/24/14          279   
2    Oracle    OR      Soft & IT      Info       01/26/14          310
2    Oracle    ORL     Software       Info       01/25/14          219
2    Oracle    ORL     Soft           IT         01/28/14          600

MonthlyAmount Funded   AppCategory  Research
37.5623       Yes       NE            NA
41.2365       No        N             NA
23.2568       Yes       OR        InProgress
25.8333       Yes       ORL           NA  
18.2189       Yes       SOF        Approved
50.0000       No        IT         Rejected
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ID  AppName  DepCode   DepName        Group     ModifiedDate   YearlyAmount 
 1    Nestle    NS      Foods         Products    01/17/14         946  
 2    Oracle    OR      Soft & IT      Info       01/26/14         589
 2    Oracle    ORL     Soft           IT         01/28/14         819

MonthlyAmount  Funded  AppCategory      Research 
78.7988          No        N             NA
49.0901         Yes       ORL            NA 
68.2189          No       IT          Rejected
```

I want to pick the recent modified date for DepCode and sum Yearly and Monthly Amount. I have tried this query and not able to get the output. Also this is a single table.

```
select B1.[ID], B1.[AppName], B2.[DepCode], B1.[DepName], B1.[Group], 
B2.ModifiedDate, B2.YearlyAmount, B2.MonthlyAmount, 
B1.[Funded], B1.[AppCategory], B1.[Research]
FROM Business B1
INNER JOIN
(select [ID], B1.[DepCode], MAX(ModifiedDate) as ModifiedDate, SUM(YearlyAmount) as YearlyAmount,
    SUM(MonthlyAmount) as MonthlyAmount 
 from Business
Group by ID, DepCode) B2
ON B1.ID = B2.ID AND B1.ModifiedDate = B2.ModifiedDate
```

Anyone please correct me or advice how to solve this as I'm a starter in SQL.

Comment: Can you add a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Here is the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01cca/4

Comment: you havent inserted any data over there..

Comment: Yes I have inserted data.

Comment: No there are no records. It just contains the `create` statement

Comment: Can you pls check now.

Comment: Pls update the link. The link changes after each alteration

Comment: Here is the updated link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dff96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated as there's a few columns where you cannot use aggregate functions - their values come from the record with the maximum date. You can use a subquery to first get the totals and the maximum date and then use that information to get the other columns

```
select B1.[ID], B1.[AppName], B2.[DepCode], B1.[DepName], B1.[Group], 
    B2.ModifiedDate, B2.YearlyAmount, B2.MonthlyAmount, 
    B1.[Funded], B1.[AppCategory], B1.[Research]
FROM Business B1
INNER JOIN
    (select [ID], DepCode, MAX(ModifiedDate) as ModifiedDate, SUM(YearlyAmount) as YearlyAmount,
        SUM(MonthlyAmount) as MonthlyAmount 
    from Business
    Group by ID, DepCode) B2
ON B1.ID = B2.ID AND B1.ModifiedDate = B2.ModifiedDate
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b168a0/1)

Comment: This is a single table and I don't have two tables like Business B1 and Business. Business is the only table I have  Since I couldn't edit to fit the page I think its mistaken.

Comment: It is a single table used twice. B1 is just an alias.

Comment: But when I run this I get an error saying invalid column name for AppName, DepCode, DepName, Group, Funded, AppCategory and Research.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I put the aliases the other way round. I already updated the query. I also created a sql fiddle for 2 records.

Comment: The query works fine now. But I am not able to ge the values for OR DepCode

Comment: Ok, I added DepCode to the inner query grouping.

Comment: If I have different DepCode under same ID then I see they get duplicated twice inthe output table.

Comment: In this case you need to remove it from the inner query and select it as `B1.[DepCode]`. You can't have it both ways - you have to decide which columns are your true grouping columns and put them in the inner query.

Comment: I have updated my code in the post. Can you pls review it, bacause I face some problems. Changes in internal query for DepCode

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your few columns doesn't have same values so that `groupby` was not working.

Since you want `recent modified date for DepCode`, `sum Yearly` and `Monthly Amount`

Try this

```
SELECT [ID], [AppName], [DepCode], 
       MAX(ModifiedDate) AS ModifiedDate,
       SUM(YearlyAmount) AS YearlyAmount,
       SUM(MonthlyAmount) AS MonthlyAmount
FROM [dbo].[Bus]
GROUP BY DepCode, ID, AppName
ORDER BY ID
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48197/10)

Comment: This is perfect, but I need to show the remaining columns as well.